# im trying to make a 8ball embed discord.js

Tags: embed, discord.js

In the console it says Argument expression expected how do i fix this?   Here is my code https://hastebin.com/imaqulixer.js

Comment: There is no code in this link.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set in your embed description:

```
returns[nr]
```

Please tell us next time your error that you have.

And please use `message.channel.send({embed:embed})` instead of the deprecated .`sendEmbed` function

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are having problems because you are trying to define your 'nr' variable inside the embed. Simply replace `.setDescription(var nr = Math.floor(Math.random()*returns.length)` with `.setDescription(nr)`, because you already defined `nr` earlier in your code.